# Python/Pandas dataframe - return column name

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Is there a way to return the name/header of a column into a string in a pandas dataframe? I want to work with a row of data which has the same prefix. The dataframe header looks like this:

```
col_00 | col_01 | ... | col_51 | bc_00 | cd_00 | cd_01 | ... | cd_90
```

I'd like to apply a function to each row, but only from `col_00` to `col_51` and to `cd_00` to `cd_90` separately. To do this, I thought I'd collect the column names into a list, fe. `to_work_with` would be the list of columns starting with the prefix 'col', apply the function to `df[to_work_with]`. Then I'd change the `to_work_with` and it would contain the list of columns starting with the 'cd' prefix et cetera. But I don't know how to iterate through the column names.

So basically, the thing I'm looking for is this function:

```
to_work_with = column names in the df that start with "thisstring"
```

How can I do that? Thank you!

Comment: Do you want ``[col for col in df.columns.values if col.startswith("thisstring")]``?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with [`str.startswith`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.startswith.html):

```
cols = df.columns[df.columns.str.startswith('cd')]
print (cols)
Index(['cd_00', 'cd_01', 'cd_02', 'cd_90'], dtype='object')
```

Sample:

```
print (df)
   col_00  col_01  col_02  col_51  bc_00  cd_00  cd_01  cd_02  cd_90
0       1       2       3       4      5      6      7      8      9

cols = df.columns[df.columns.str.startswith('cd')]
print (cols)
Index(['cd_00', 'cd_01', 'cd_02', 'cd_90'], dtype='object')

#if want apply some function for filtered columns only
def f(x):
    return x + 1

df[cols] = df[cols].apply(f)    
print (df)
   col_00  col_01  col_02  col_51  bc_00  cd_00  cd_01  cd_02  cd_90
0       1       2       3       4      5      7      8      9     10
```

Another solution with `list comprehension`:

```
cols = [col for col in df.columns if col.startswith("cd")]
print (cols)
['cd_00', 'cd_01', 'cd_02', 'cd_90']
```

Comment: Amazing! Thank you! :)

Comment: Glad can help you! Good luck!

Comment: Hi @jezrael very good one. I am able to create the Dataframe with values by just giving df[cols]. Can you please let me know the use of apply function there ? Sorry I am still in a learning process. So this might be a basic question to you.

Comment: @JKC - It is only a example for apply some function for columns filtered by `startswith` :)

Comment: No problem, I add ot to answer ;)